# SQL Server Indexing -- Any benefits of creating a nonclustered index on composite key fields?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have a PK on two fields on my table (UtilityId, int & ACCT_NO varchar(100))
I really don't know if the order makes a difference, but this is the code (with UtilityId first):

```
ALTER table AccountAddress
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountAddresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UtilityId,ACCT_NO)
```

If I want to query the table on UtilityId, would creating an index on UtilityId be beneficial (maybe I need not do that, because the system has a PK defined--by virtue of which indexing is already there).

Conversely, If I want to query on ACCT_NO, which is the second field in the index definition, then, would creating an index on ACCT_NO be beneficial, or not really?

Comment: 1) No, indexes are hierarchical. The server can already find any rows with that value just by seeking. That's not the case with ACCT_NO, where the server would have to search all index records to find which of them contain the predicate as the next value.

Comment: 2) Yes, depending on the query. Using an index still means loading data. Depending on the query and statistics, the server may decide it's cheaper to use the PK. If you join two tables by PK for example, the PK index is going to be used anyway.

Comment: ok, thanks.  This is what I suspected.  I can accept that as answer, unless anybody posts any objections.... (if you choose to post as an answer).

Comment: I'm going to disagree with you on point 1. Certain queries ex: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AccountAddress` could benefit from a narrow nonclustered index (even on one of the columns in the composite key) as SQL Server will choose the smallest index. It's a minor edge case, but there are definitely circumstances where this could be relevant.

Comment: The general answer to this question is always "it depends". If you want to know, then do it and compare the plans. Much depends on the queries you use. A specific index might benefit a specific query but there is a cost for each index. If the "benefit" is minor and/or rarely realized, does that outweigh the cost of the space used for it and the cost of the engine to keep it current (along with maintenance costs of reindexing, re-organizing, generating stats, etc.)?

Comment: And note that a non-unique non-clustered index is physically stored as a unique non-clustered index with the remaining clustered index keys added as trailing index columns.  So an index on UtilityId is stored as an index on (UtilityId,ACCT_NO), and an index on (ACCT_NO) is stored as an index on (ACCT_NO,UtilityId).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "ordinary" (SQL Server "relationnal" AKA B-Tree+) index is a sort of vector. And the vector path is compound of all the columns in the key, in the key list order.

The efficiency of seeks depends of the "ways" you try to retrieve your data
As an example :

```
CREATE INDEX X ON T (A, B, C)
```

Will be efficient for equal seeks in theses cases :

- A and B and C
- A and B
- A

Buth won't be efficient for equal seeks :

- B
- C
- B and C

But depending of the optimizer, it can do a scan on the index if the cardinality estimator found that there is a few number of rows to return.

If you want to query on ACCT_NO only, you can create a specific index to improve performances.

The efficiency of an index is relative to the predicates you have in your query (WHERE clause, ON clause of joins, HAVING, CASE…). This is called "sargable" (Search ARGument ABLE).
As an example LIKE '%anyword%' is never sargable, whatever index you have.